# create autoscaling group from launch configuration error: The t2.micro instance type does not support specifying CpuOptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to create an autoscaling group from a launch configuration which was created from an ec2 AMI. However, in the second step, 'Configure Settings', I get an error message when I click 'Next'. I tried reviewing my first step but could not find anything on CpuOptions nor could I find anything about CpuOptions in the launch configuration that I specified as part of the autoscaling group.

Autoscaling group
[image: Error message from autoscaling setup]

Launch template

[image]

Comment: How about including the launch template in your question? This error is almost certainly referring to the "Unlimited CPU" option that is available on T3 instance types.

Comment: I've now included a screenshot of the template console. Again I tried to look at the template and couldn't find any configure cpu options for the t2.micro instance or the image the template works off of.

Comment: You still aren't providing enough information in your question. What is in your launch template's "Advanced Details" tab?

Comment: Advanced Details provided

Comment: What if you change `T2/T3 Unlimited` so it just shows a `-` blank value instead of "Standard"?

Comment: I get the same error message after changing the launch template to both 'unlimited' and  "don't include in launch template" under 'Credit Specification' in 'Advanced details'.

Comment: Are you specifying any of these options somehow? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html#instance-specify-cpu-options I'm not even sure where that would show up in the launch template.

Comment: No I didn't specify these because, as the error message states, the t2.micro doesn't support these options. I couldn't find these options in the launch template either.

Answer (score 3):

Did you create the template from an existing t2.micro instance? I had the same problem when I did that. The problem went away when I created a new template from scratch, i.e. manually selecting the AMI and instance type etc.

Comment: In the end, that was what I did. This seems to be a bug in AWS as others on the AWS forum have encountered this as well. I'd say at this point to avoid creating launch templates from AMIs and manually create your launch templates.

Comment: so, it's must be a new bug due to an update or something. Because I follow a tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hLmDS179YE ) Oct 2019. He did it great, but when I do the same thing, this error hit me. And the worst part is, likely there's no solution yet, at least on the official site as far as i know.